# Saber cuando utilizar las palabras claves new y override

Tags: c#

¿Qué diferencia existe entre utilizar las palabras claves `new` y `override` al crear un método en una clase que hereda de otra la cual tiene un método con el mismo nombre?

Un ejemplo básico con el metodo clasico `ToString()`

```
private string ToString()
{
    return "";
}
```

El compilador me avisa que si quiero que la clase actual implemente de nuevo el método agregue la palabra `override` y si quiero ocultarlo le agregue el `new`.
Sin embargo, no me deja utilizar `override`, ya que mi método es `private` e intento tenerlo como apoyo a otros métodos en mi propia clase, trato de encapsularlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando heredas de una clase, la clase hija hereda todas sus propiedades y métodos qué no esten marcadas como privadas y van a tener exactamente la misma funcionalidad.

Pero si quieres cambiar la funcionalidad de un método éste debe de estar marcado como **virtual** en la clase base y en la clase hija se debe de poner **override** para indicar que vamos a cambiar la funcionalidad de ese método y éste debe de tener la misma firma (mismos parametros de entrada como de salida).

¿Qúe pasa si no está marcada como virtual o quiero cambiar el valor de retorno? Aqui es donde debes de poner **new** para que se ejecute el método de la clase hija y el de la clase base quede oculto (como no se sobreescribio con **override** aún existe)

Aqui algunos ejemplos

```
//Todos heredan de Base
public class Base
{
    protected string Nombre;

    public Base()
    {
        Nombre = "Base";
    }
    //Regresa un string
    public virtual string quienSoy()
    {
        return "Soy " + Nombre;
    }
}

//Clase que sobreescribe el metodo quienSoy
public class A : Base
{
    public A(string nombre)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public override string quienSoy()
    {
        return "Me llamo " + Nombre;
    }
}

//Clase que oculta el metodo quienSoy
public class B : Base
{
    public B(string nombre)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public new string quienSoy()
    {
        return "Ni nombre es " + Nombre;
    }
}

//Clase que oculta y cambia la salida de el metodo quienSoy
public class C : Base
{
    public C(string nombre)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }
    //Ya no regresa un string
    public new StringBuilder quienSoy()
    {
        return new StringBuilder("My name is " + Nombre);
    }
}
```

Si ejecutamos el metodo quienSoy de la clase base tenemos

```
Base claseBase = new Base();
Console.WriteLine(claseBase.quienSoy());
//La salida será
//Soy Base
```

Si creamos una clase A y ejecutamos el metodo quienSoy tenemos

```
A claseA = new A("A");
Console.WriteLine(claseA.quienSoy());
//Salida:
//Me llamo A
```

Ahora si hacemos un casting de la clase A a una clase Base tenemos la misma salida, ya que sobreescribimos el método de la clase base

```
A claseA = new A("A");
Base clase = claseA;
Console.WriteLine(clase.quienSoy());
//Salida
//Me llamo A
```

Ejecutando la clase B

```
B claseB = new B("B");
Console.WriteLine(claseB.quienSoy());
//Salida
//Mi nombre es B
```

Si hacemos el casting a una clase base vamos a invocar al método oculto quienSoy de base

```
B claseB = new B("B");
Base clase = claseB;
Console.WriteLine(clase.quienSoy());
//Salida
//Soy B
```

Ya por último probamos la clase C que cambia el valor de retorno de un string por un StringBuilder

```
C claseC = new C("C");
Console.WriteLine(claseC.quienSoy().Append(" !!"));
//Salida
//My name is C !!
```

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia es en como el compilador determina cual implementan utilizar. el `override` que se utiliza para sobrescribir métodos virtuales o implementar métodos abstractos. el `new` permite sobrescribir los métodos que por arquitectura no se pensó que fuera necesario re-implentar, pero en este caso se ejecutara el metodo si y solo si se trata al objeto como un elemento de la misma clase que le hizo `new` al metodo, encaso de castiarlo a un tipo del cual hereda, o sus hijos, no tendran acceso a este metodo.

Ejemplo

```
public class Padre
{
    public virtual void Hola()
    {
    }
}

public class Hijo : Padre
{
    public override void Hola()
    {
    }
}

Padre a = new Hijo();
a.Hola();                      // ejecuta el de la clase Hijo.
```

Ejemplo new

```
public class Padre
{
    public void Hola()
    {
    }
}

public class Hijo : Padre
{
    public new void Hola()
    {
    }
}

Padre a = new Hijo();
Hijo b = new Hijo();

a.Hola();                      // ejecuta el de la clase Padre.
b.Hola();                      // ejecuta el de la clase Hijo.
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/whats-the-difference-between-override-and-new/

Answer (score 1):

Para poder utilizar `override` o `new`, el metodo debe ser `public` o `protected`, de lo contrario  no podrás.

Aqui algunos datos para que lo tengas en cuenta antes de utilizar `override` o `new`:

`override` se utiliza cuando quieres sobreescribir el metodo para modificar su comportamiento:

```
public class Base
{
  public virtual string ObtenerMensaje()
  {
    return "base";
  }
}

public class Hija : Base
{
  public override string ObtenerMensaje()
 {
    return "hija";
 }
}

Base base = new Hija();
Console.WriteLine(base.ObtenerMensaje()); // hija..
```

Mientras que `new` se utiliza cuando el método base no esta marcado como `virtual` y aun asi se quiere modificar o ocultar la implementacion del tipo base:

```
 public class Base
    {
      public string ObtenerMensaje()
      {
        return "base";
      }
    }

public class Hija : Base
{
  public new string ObtenerMensaje()
  {
    return "hija";
  }
}

Hija base = new Hija();
Console.WriteLine(base.ObtenerMensaje()); // hija..
```

---

Ahora bien, hay un comportamiento fundamental entre ambos que puede llevar a muchos errores si no se sabe utilizar: `new` siempre *utilizara la implementacion del tipo de destino* aunque en el objeto inicializado se oculte la implementacion con `new`.

Por ejemplo:

```
 public class Base
    {
      public string ObtenerMensaje()
      {
        return "base";
      }
    }

public class Hija : Base
{
  public new string ObtenerMensaje()
  {
    return "hija";
  }
}

Base baseInstancia = new Hija();
Hija hijaInstancia = new Hija();

Console.WriteLine(hijaInstancia.ObtenerMensaje()); // imprime hija
Console.WriteLine(baseInstancia.ObtenerMensaje()); // imprime base, no hija..
```

Cuando se utiliza el objeto `baseInstancia`, se retorna la implementacion del tipo `Base` que retorna `"base"`. Mientras que como el tipo del objeto `hijaInstancia` es `Hija` se utiliza su implementacion. Aunque hija oculte la implementacion con el operador `new`, `baseInstancia` utiliza la implementacion del tipo `Base`.

**¿Cuando utilizar el operador new?**

Un escenario seria cuando utilizas una libreria o dll de un tercero y tiene un metodo o propiedad no marcado como como `virtual`, pero te gustaria *sobreescribirlo* para utilizar tu propia implementacion.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra **override** se usa generalmente para implementar interfaces (implementar métodos virtuales de clases bases), mientras que **new** te permite "pisar" o reescribir un método de una clase base, sea virtual o no.

Con respecto a tu pregunta sobre new, podrías hacer algo así si lo quisieras:

```
class Uno
{
    public void ver()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hola Uno!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Dos : Uno
{
    public new void ver()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hola Dos!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Claro. Te lo explico arriba.